# What does '|| {}' do

Tags: javascript

I was digging around some older javascript code when i've come across the following piece of code:

```
constructor: function (data) { 
    DataArr = data || {}
    if (DataArr.fileId == undefined) 
       { .... }
}
```

The values passed as data are always an array:

```
{fileId: 'someFileId', fileName: 'someFilename' ... }
```

**Question:**
So what does `data || {}` exactly do and in what context should I use it?

**Note:** The code uses both `jquery` and `extjs`. Perhaps this function is only available in one of those frameworks.

I thank you for your time.

**Note2**: I know it probably has something to do with the array (e.g. exposing the values). But i was looking for some deeper info.

Comment: If `data` is falsy (usually undefined) set it as empty object, otherwise, `data.fileId` would throw an uncaught type error.

Comment: @A.Wolff My bad. I was adjusting the code snippet above to represent the actual code. And in de course of that I edited the wrong field. Will adjust it immediatly

Comment: As as side note, `DataArr` isn't an array

Comment: @A.Wolff If DataArr is not an Array what type of object is it exactly? As it is either set to `data` (Array) or `{}` (empty array)

Comment: It is just a plain object. Array are particular objects: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataArr = data || {}.
```

This is not related to jquery or any library.It's a javascript

Hope you understand `||` is stand for OR Operator

So,Here is condition is if data is there then add data to DataArr else initialize to empty object

Here is the snap from Google Chrome inspector[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Oh i see. Didn't know that there was in 'if' implied/hidden in there. Now i does make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

`data = data || {}`

**is same to**

```
if(data) {
    data = data
} else {
    data = {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if data is true or not empty data varible will hold data other wise it will be init as blank object

```
data = data || {}
```